# PHP CSV to Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, associative-array

I have a CSV file that I need to import into an associative array. The data looks like this:

```
 "General Mills Cereal",http://sidom.com/dyn_li/60.0.75.0/Retailers/Saws/120914_20bp4_img_8934.jpg,$2.25,"9-17.12 oz., select varieties","Valid Sep 14, 2012 - Sep 20, 2012",Saws,"Grocery"
```

I wan to transform this data into an array where I can grab values like this:

```
 $items[$row]['title'];
 $items[$row]['imgurl'];
 $items[$row]['itemprice'];
 $items[$row]['itemsize'];
 $items[$row]['expir'];
 $items[$row]['storename'];
 $items[$row]['storetype'];
```

Where the elements above correspond to my CSV file. How can I import this file into such an array?

Comment: Have a look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the built-in function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
There's a simple usage example there also.

Answer (score 4):

[`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) will give you a numerically indexed array.

Once you have read all records in to say `$rawData`, which has a structure along the lines of:

```
$rawData = array(0 => array(0 => "General Mills Cereal",
                            1 => "http://sidom.com/dyn_li/60.0.75.0/Retailers/Saws/120914_20bp4_img_8934.jpg"
                            2 => "$2.25",
                            3 => "9-17.12 oz.",
                            4 => "select varieties",
                            5 => "Valid Sep 14, 2012 - Sep 20, 2012",
                            6 => "Saws",
                            7 => "Grocery"),
                 ...);
```

To convert this `$rawData` array to what you want, you can do something like this:

```
$fields = array('title', 'imgurl', 'itemprice', 'itemsize',
                'expir', 'storename', 'storetype');

$data = array_map(function($cRow) uses ($fields) {
            return array_combine($fields, $cRow);
        }, $rawData);
```

Comment: Just a small correction - "uses" should be "use". Otherwise this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

See below URL

[CSV to Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801895/csv-to-associative-array)

Try it

run over the csv file line by line, and insert to array like:

```
$array = array();
$handle = @fopen("file.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

       $array[$line[0]][$line[1]][$line[2]] = $line[3];
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done this.

```
<?php
$file = "galerie.csv";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    $galerie[$data[0]]["alt"] = $data[1];
    $galerie[$data[0]]["caption"] = $data[2];
   }
fclose($handle);
print_r($galerie);
?>
```